# Question about iterated limit and limit for a function on $\Bbb R^2$.

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
> 0,  & \text{if $x\ne0$ and $y\ne0$ } \\
> 1, & \text{if either $x=0$ or $y=0$}
> \end{cases}
> \text{ defined on } \Bbb R^2 $
> Show that $\lim \limits_{x\to a}f(x,y)$ and $\lim \limits_{y\to b}f(x,y)$ both exist, and $\lim \limits_{x\to a}\Bigl(\lim \limits_{y\to b}f(x,y) \Bigr)=\lim \limits_{y\to b}\Bigl(\lim \limits_{x\to a}f(x,y) \Bigr)=L$ for all $a,b\in \Bbb R$. Does $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ exist?

I think $\lim \limits_{x\to a}f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $y=0$ } \\
0, & \text{if $y\ne0$}
\end{cases}$, and $\lim \limits_{y\to b}f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x=0$ } \\
0, & \text{if $x\ne0$}
\end{cases}_.$

But for $\lim \limits_{x\to a}\Bigl(\lim \limits_{y\to b}f(x,y) \Bigr)=\lim \limits_{y\to b}\Bigl(\lim \limits_{x\to a}f(x,y) \Bigr)$, what should I do?

$\lim \limits_{h\to 0}f(h,h)=0$, but $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}f(h,0)=1$, so I think $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\to a}\left(\lim_{y\to b}f(x,y)\right)$ becomes $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ where
$$g(x)=\lim_{y\to b}f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 1 & x = 0 \\
0 & x \ne 0\end{cases}$$
and we see that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$. It's the same for the other iterated limit. And the double limit doesn't exist for the reason you gave.

Comment: Can I say that for any $a$, when $x\to a$, it implies $x\ne 0$, so $\lim \limits_{x\to a}g(x)=0$?

Comment: @StevenLu Not that it implies it but you can say that for $x\to a$, you can pick a small enough $\delta$ in the definition of limit (neighborhood around $a$) so as to exclude $x=0$.